# Add category automatically while adding post

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using wordpress for a News site. 
There is place called Headlines with following ACF code. Which adds posts to headline of the website.

```
array (
                        'key' => 'field_53e3e2fc67dc4',
                        'label' => 'Headlines',
                        'name' => 'hp_headlines',
                        'prefix' => '',
                        'type' => 'repeater',
                        'instructions' => '',
                        'required' => 0,
                        'conditional_logic' => 0,
                        'wrapper' => array (
                            'width' => '',
                            'class' => '',
                            'id' => '',
                        ),
                        'min' => '',
                        'max' => '',
                        'layout' => 'row',
                        'button_label' => 'Add Headline',
                        'sub_fields' => array (
                            array (
                                'key' => 'field_54621f720bfdc',
                                'label' => 'Headline Type',
                                'name' => 'hp_headline_type',
                                'prefix' => '',
                                'type' => 'radio',
                                'instructions' => '',
                                'required' => 1,
                                'conditional_logic' => 0,
                                'wrapper' => array (
                                    'width' => '',
                                    'class' => '',
                                    'id' => '',
                                ),
                                'choices' => array (
                                    'url' => 'URL',
                                    'article' => 'Article',
                                ),
                                'other_choice' => 0,
                                'save_other_choice' => 0,
                                'default_value' => 'url',
                                'layout' => 'horizontal',
                            ),
                            array (
                                'key' => 'field_54621fa20bfdd',
                                'label' => 'URL',
                                'name' => 'hp_headline_url',
                                'prefix' => '',
                                'type' => 'url',
                                'instructions' => '',
                                'required' => 1,
                                'conditional_logic' => array (
                                    array (
                                        array (
                                            'field' => 'field_54621f720bfdc',
                                            'operator' => '==',
                                            'value' => 'url',
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'wrapper' => array (
                                    'width' => '',
                                    'class' => '',
                                    'id' => '',
                                ),
                                'default_value' => '',
                                'placeholder' => 'http://',
                            ),
                            array (
                                'key' => 'field_53e3e34067dc5',
                                'label' => 'Article',
                                'name' => 'hp_headline_article',
                                'prefix' => '',
                                'type' => 'post_object',
                                'instructions' => '',
                                'required' => 1,
                                'conditional_logic' => array (
                                    array (
                                        array (
                                            'field' => 'field_54621f720bfdc',
                                            'operator' => '==',
                                            'value' => 'article',
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'wrapper' => array (
                                    'width' => '',
                                    'class' => '',
                                    'id' => '',
                                ),
                                'post_type' => array (
                                    0 => 'post',
                                ),
                                'taxonomy' => '',
                                'allow_null' => 0,
                                'multiple' => 0,
                                'return_format' => 'id',
                                'ui' => 1,
                            ),                               
                        ),
```

Which creates a field to add already added posts to a list of headlines. 
Now I want these fields to be added to category "xyz" automatically as I press the update button. And I have no Idea which file to edit.

[image]

Comment: no clear, what you are trying to achieve, please explain bit more and add screenshot if possible

Comment: Thank you. 
I want to link a category and a post using php code. But I did not found the file to do so. 
The ACF above is used to create the fields, after whose submission I want to link a category and the post selected in above field.

Comment: you mean you want to  assign category to the post?

Comment: Here Hello world post is selected, so "Save Options" is pressed what I want is to put the Hello world post under. category $cat.
 And I did not found the PHP file where I can apply wp_set_post_categories function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need use save_post action, add this code in your functions.php change cat ID wit your cat id's

```
function set_my_categories($post_ID){
  if(wp_is_post_autosave($post_ID) || wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
  return $post_ID;
  }
  wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, array(49,13) );
  }
  add_action('save_post', 'set_my_categories');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try this and get back.